# is email address embedded in PHP code on webpage really hidden from external world?

Tags: php, html

If I have a contact form with PHP embedded in it that contains a php variable with my email address, is there anyway for the external world to view that email address?

If I right-click to view source on the webpage, the PDF section containing the email address is not displayed, leading me to believe my email address is securely hidden.

Is it really hidden, or am I fooling myself?

UPDATE

Here's the code I'm using:

https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Comment: probably need to share some code to answer this

Comment: If you're talking about `$to = 'example@domain.com'; `, then that is safely hidden from the browser as long as it's not used anywhere else in HTML rendering.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena, yes, that is what I'm referring to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is hidden from the outside world.  As long as you aren't echoing it out into your page contents, no one can see it.